# Bundling Sql scripts to execute them in a secure way

Tags: sql, unix

I am generating CSV files using an Oracle SQL scripts in a Unix environment.

The code is visible to other users. How can I can encrypt or bundle the code and the generated CSV files?

Answer (score 1):

unix has file system privileges.  you should set those to protect the directory where you are working.